# Convert links to images to images in a .docx

Tags: microsoft-word, html, docx

I have converted a DOCX file to HTML using Microsoft Word 2010, now I want to do the opposite, that is, convert this HTML back to DOCX. But Microsoft Word doesn't include all the pictures in the DOCX file; it only links them to the folder containing these pictures, therefore the size of the new DOCX file is very small.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that is built into MS Word that can fix this. If you want it done, you will have to look for other tools that can help you, or you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've googled a lot for "linked images to embedded images solutions for Word 2010"
& just came across this...

this might be a good solution for users working upto Word 2010:

[Transform linked images to embedded images](https://superuser.com/questions/294978/transform-linked-images-to-embedded-images)