# Converting/pasting images in Word as an embedded picture and not a link

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I've 3 related questions.

1. How do I paste images from an email to Word as NOT a link, but rather an embedded image within the document?
2. How do I convert linked images within Word to embedded images. Under File->Edit Link to Files, I can see HTTP links. After waiting for a long time for that window to load before I can edit anything, I tried either the "Break Link" button or the "Save picture in document" checkbox, but neither changes are persistent. When I go back to "Edit Link to Files" I still see the images as links.
3. How do I see which images in the document are links?

Comment: Would you mind to share a screenshot when you right-click the linked images in Word? Click Remove Link to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the image in email and click on 'copy' from the menu. The image gets copied in the clipboard. This can be pasted directly into word document.
2. Refer to this [Transform linked images to embedded images](https://superuser.com/questions/294978/transform-linked-images-to-embedded-images?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. However, like I said, I've tried both break link and save picture in document options, and neither options seem to stick.

Comment: @user1118764 Are you attempting to break the link while editing the document that is still attached to the email? Try saving the attachment locally and then breaking the link. If that still doesn't work, do a web search for AuthorTec Link, its a free add-in for changing picture links.

Comment: How do I figure out which image is the linked one?