# Convert Word docx embedded images to links

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word .docx with a lot of images that is getting absurdly large.  I want to have all images saved as links to separate files without embedding a copy in the .docx.  How can I do this?

([This Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/294978/297822) shows how to convert linked images to embedded; I want to do the opposite.)

Answer (score 1):

### Save your document as a web page.

This creates a folder that will hold all of your images.

1. Close the file.
2. If you want your images in a different folder, move them. If you want rename them.
3. Reopen your .docx file and for each image in the file, go to that image and delete it. Replace it with your newly created image that matches and insert as a link.